# Obsolete T-SQL programming features in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, obsolete

We have lots of stored procedures written in SQL Server 2005. After database migrated from 2005 to 2008 all of them seem to be functional as before. Now we need to migrate to 2008 R2. So the question I have is:

Is there any T-SQL programming features are obsolete in 2008 R2 comparing to 2005?

That's important for us to know so we can update all sprocs accordingly.

Also, is there any other implications for migrating from 2005 to 2008 R2 in terms of stored procedures?

I would appreciate your answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft calls this kind of thing a "Breaking Change", and publishes an article with each Sql Server release that covers all known breaking changes.  The article for 2008 R2 is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179.aspx

Comment: Thanks Joel, I can see now that GROUP BY statements do have breaking change.